# MySQL second auto increment field based on foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, innodb

I've come across this problem numerous times but haven't found a "MySQL way" to solve the issue as such - I have a database that contains **users** and **reports**. Each **report** has an **id** which I display as a **report number** to my users.

The main complaint is that users are confused as to why reports have gone missing from their system. This is not actually the case. It is actually that they are recognizing a gap between their IDs and assume that these are missing reports, when in actual fact, it is simply becasue another user has filled in this auto-incrementing gap.

I need to know if there is a way to do this in MySQL:

Is it possible that I can have a **second** auto-increment field called **report_number** which is **based on a user_id** field which has a different set of auto-increments per user?

e.g.

```
|------|---------|---------------|
|  id  | user_id | report_number |
|------|---------|---------------|
|  1   |    1    |       1       |
|  2   |    1    |       2       |
|  3   |    1    |       3       |
|  4   |    2    |       1       |
|  5   |    1    |       4       |
|  6   |    1    |       5       |
|  7   |    2    |       2       |
|  8   |    3    |       1       |
|  9   |    3    |       2       |
|------|---------|---------------|
```

I am using **InnoDB** for this as it is quite heavily weighted with foreign-keys. It appears to complain when I add a second auto increment field, but I wasn't sure if there was a different way to do this?

Comment: This is usually solved client side.  The client can label the rows incrementally.  It doesn't even need the `report_number` to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`MyISAM` supports the second column with auto increment, but **`InnoDB` doesn't**.

For InnoDB you might create a trigger `BEFORE INSERT` to get the max value of the reportid and add one to the value.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER report_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON reports
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.`report_id` = (SELECT MAX(report_id) + 1 FROM reports WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

If you can use MyISAM instead, in the documentation of MySQL page there is an example:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
    ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
    ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
    ('bird','ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id;
```

Which returns:

```
+--------+----+---------+
| grp    | id | name    |
+--------+----+---------+
| fish   |  1 | lax     |
| mammal |  1 | dog     |
| mammal |  2 | cat     |
| mammal |  3 | whale   |
| bird   |  1 | penguin |
| bird   |  2 | ostrich |
+--------+----+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Right one with IFNULL:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER salons_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON salon
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.salon_id = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(salon_id) + 1 FROM salon WHERE owner = NEW.owner), 1);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think mysql doesnt support two auto_increment columns. you can  create report number using information schema.

```
select NULL from information_schema.columns
```

Answer (score -1):

MySQl does not support two auto incremented fields, if you need then create another table, set the other field which you want to be as auto incremented and you must set up a relationship with these two tables.